# Creating a Python Virtual environement with the command python3 -m venv venv points to the wrong site packages directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

OS=Pop_OS 22.04  Python version 3.10.6
I am having problems with the path to the virtual environment when I use the python -m venv command. These are the commands I am using to test the problem:

```
cd 
mkdir testenv
cd testenv
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install django
django-admin startproject website .
python manage.py runserver
```

I kept it simple on purpose and on the virtual machine it works, on my workstation it gives the error.

On my workstation after creating the virtual environment, I use pip to install django and run start project. This has worked many times.  After I updated something in my python 3.10.6 system installation, django and other pip installed packages fail to import.

So I installed a virtualbox version of my pop os and followed the same sequence of steps. Django on the virtual machine worked just like it always used to do on my workstation.

Searching the internet and stack overflow I got the advice about not moving the venv file once created.  I had not moved the project folder I was working on, but still I created a testenv folder and created the virtual environment on my workstation.  Django still failed to start.
Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/echeadle/testenv/manage.py", line 11, in main
     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
   
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
  
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/echeadle/testenv/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
   main()
   File "/home/echeadle/testenv/manage.py", line 13, in main
   raise ImportError(
   ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

The only difference i can see is when I run python -m site.
This is my workstation that is failing:

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/echeadle/testenv',
    '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/echeadle/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/echeadle/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

This is the result of the same command (python -m site) on the system that is working:

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/echeadle/testenv',
    '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
    '/home/echeadle/testenv/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/echeadle/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/echeadle/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

On my workstation, I ran the shell, imported site and looked around, but I cannot find information about how the python -m venv command uses the site function.  All I know is that on my workstation this is the only thing I have found that might be an issue.

See comments below, but a temporary fix is:

```
cd 
mkdir testenv
cd testenv
export PYTHONPATH='home/echeadle/testenv/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages'
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install django
django-admin startproject website .
python manage.py runserver
```

If you export the PYTHONPATH before you create the virtual environment, the fix for the life of the venv is permanent.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you added the exact sequence of the steps you used to: 1. create a venv; 2. activate the venv; 3. install packages within the venv. 

Also, what do you mean by "I updated something in my python 3.10.6 system installation"?

Comment: I thought it was obvious from the paragraphs about what I tried.  But this is the first question I have asked so I am not surprised by your comment.  I will go back and add the information.

Comment: I updated something, means I think I ran apt-get install for something to do with python, or when i ran my software updates, i know python libraries were updated, but I paid no attention., because python has been working flawlessly and it was a normal update.

Comment: `dist-packages` is used by Debian-based systems to install dependencies for OS applications that require Python. Can you find `testenv/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages` in your workstation?

Comment: Yes, I do have the  testenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages directory.  In site-packages is a django directory and a Django-4.1.6.dist-info directory.   I can run the django-admin startproject executable after I source the virtual environment, but when I run manage.py runserver, it cannot find django.  Why the path to the site-packages directory does not show up when I run python -m site is one of the things I do not understand.

Comment: The problem is that when i run the python -m venv venv command, the paths are not set correctly.   As a hack I created a site-packages.pth file in  '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages' directory and entered the full path ('/home/echeadle/testenv/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages') to where pip installed django and everything works.   So something is preventing the command python -m venv from setting the correct path.

Comment: Since this problem is over 14 years old, and I am too new to python to be able to troubleshoot a language issue very efficiently, I will  just add an export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:'/home/echeadle/testenv3/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages' to my code until I can figure it out.

Comment: If you add the export PYTHONPATH variable before you create the venv, then the fix is permanent.  You have to remember to change the full path to the new folder you are creating.  In my case I created a testenv4 folder and before I ran python -m venv venv I did an export PYTHONPATH='/home/echeadle/testenv4/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages'    I figured out that PYTHONPATH was not set, so instead of using PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH, I ensured that I would not add wrong paths to sys.path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem I submitted where python -m venv returns an incorrect path the virtual environment's site-packages directory, on jetbrains website.

The problem was, in my .bash_aliases I had alias python="/usr/bin/python3"
This was the problem. The explanation is found at the link below.

[Fix for incorrect path to site-packages](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010342419-Terminal-instance-not-using-project-s-venv)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).